# What does a Maven Artifact means in a context of runnable jar project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a project which is being managed by `maven`, let's say it's a web-server (but it can any project which is being run by its jar)

maven will create an artifact of this project and even store it on the local repo (or even on a remote if configured)

but those artifacts have no meaning outside their context, I won't have this jar as a dependency in some other project, so is there some other merits for artifacts in this scenario (it won't act as a dependency in any other project) ?

is there a way to disable this behavior of maven? (I still would like to use the version though and other maven abilities like it's hooks and plugins)

I currently doing that with `mvn package` and state the specific build cycles and plugins I want to run, looking for easier kill switch, like disable the **install** phase completely, by configuration or smth, so even when using mvn install it will do all previous phases but the `install`

Comment: I don't understand your question. `is there a way to disable this behavior of maven? ` What exactly do you mean by that? And what do you mean by this: ` currently doing that with mvn package and state the specific build cycles and plugins I want to run, looking for easier kill switch (if there is...)` ?

Comment: Yes you have updated the last paragraph but doesn't really lighten the information.. Please explain based on an example what you are doing or what does not work as you like to work ...If you don't like to execute `install` phase simply use `mvn verify` instead ? See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: @rkosegi, yes, this thread has the answer I was looking for, closing the question, thx